# На айпадах не работает margin

Tags: html, css

Уважаемые специалисты
На сайте есть правило css `margin:0 auto; width:1012px;` которое центрирует весь блок но это не работает на айфонах и айпадах кто знает чем можно заменить эти правила для этих устройств.

Всем заранее спасибо!

Comment: Спасибо что никто не помог! Иногда это очень полезно для развития

Answer (score 2):

Это известная проблема, на stackoverflow какое-то решения гуглятся, у меня ни одно из них в аналогичной ситуации не сработало, поэтому был использован костыль - добавлен мета-тег `<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=0.6" />` в шапку сайта (число нужно подгонять)